# How to insert data in a Json array into a database via a ajax request in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, pivot-table, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and using version 5.2. I have two models Tour and City which are having a many to many relationship in between. I have already created 3 tables, tours, cities and city_tour in by database and defined the relationships in the models.
Models are as follows.

**Tour Model**

```
class Tour extends Model{

public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\City');
}  }
```

**City Model**

```
class City extends Model{

public function tours()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour');
}  }
```

I'm using the a ajax post request to pass data store method in my TourController. My *ajax request* is as follows.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){ 

    var path = JSON.stringify(route);
    var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

    $.post("/tour",
    {
        tourname: $("#name").val(),
        startpoint: $("#select_startpoint").val(),
        endpoint : $("#select_endpoint").val(),
        waypoints : path,
        '_token': token       
    },function(){
        alert("Path has been saved");
        window.location.href = "/tour";
    });
});
```

Here the variable *path* is a javascript array and i have converted it json string in order to pass in to server. And It contains names of cities as strings.

My *Store* method is as follows.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   

    $tour = new Tour;
    $tour->tourname = $request->tourname;
    $tour->startpoint = $request->startpoint;
    $tour->endpoint = $request->endpoint;        
    $tour->save();

    $json = $request->waypoints;
    $waypoints= json_decode($json);

    foreach($waypoints as $point){

        $city = City::where('name', '=', $point->name)->firstOrFail();
        $cityid = $city->city_id;

        $tour->cities()->attach($cityid);  
    }  

    redirect()->action('TourController@index');
}
```

As there is a m:n relationship between City and Tour I want to add my cities in to a intermediate table. Here as my cities are in a array, I retrieved their city_id and try to attach that id in to the table one by one using an for each loop. My code is as above. Can any one help.

Comment: Show us the structure of `path` variable.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki The structure is like this.`["City1","City2","City3","City3","City4"]`

Comment: :( then why you get the `name` attribute in `$point->name` where it's not exist?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki My mistake. Then I changed the code as `$city = City::where('name', '=', $point)->firstOrFail();` But the data is saved only to tours table, it doesn't save data in to the city_tour table.

Comment: Okay try to add the model code then we could check if the relationships are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code need to be changed as below:

from:   `$cityid = $city->city_id;`

to:   `$cityid = $city->id;`